# Ext grid PagingToolbar does not show on IE

Tags: javascript, extjs4, border, viewport, pagingtoolbar

I have Viewport as below. The `panel2` has a grid which has a `PagingToolbar`. It does not show in IE, it shows little in FF. If I don't have the north region, it works fine.
What can be the reason?

```
Ext.create('Ext.Viewport', {
    layout: 'border',
    border : 0,
    items: [
         {
            region: 'north',
            html : 'Some html'
         },
            { region: 'center',
            layout:'fit',
            split : true,
            items : [panel1, panel2]
         }
    ]
    });
```

Here is a similar example : http://jsfiddle.net/edgMV/20/
The buttons are not showing up.

Comment: @LaurenZonneveld Yeah `panel2` is hidden until `panel1` is submitted.

Comment: In that case card layout may be better suited.

Comment: @LaurenZonneveld There is `split` property on `viewport`? I have IE 9, it happens in FF as well, it is just little better in FF.

Comment: Nope, my bad, fixed in example. From documentation: This configuration option is to be applied to the child items managed by this layout. Each region with split:true will get a Splitter that allows for manual resizing of the container. **Except for the center region**.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking at your Fiddle but there are several things wrong.

- CSS looks like an incomplete Neptune stylesheet
- By doing this: `items: resultsPanel` in your region panels, you are creating a new panel inside that panel
- You are setting incorrect configuration on elements, my advice is to look at the [ExtJS documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/) for this, it lists all the valid configuration options
- You might want to look at the [MVC architecture tutorial](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/guide/application_architecture)

Now for the layout, I don't know what you want exactly, but this might be close:
http://jsfiddle.net/laurenzonneveld/kVUEU/4/

```
var navigate = function (panel, direction) {
    var layout = panel.getLayout();
    layout[direction]();
    Ext.getCmp('move-prev').setDisabled(!layout.getPrev());
    Ext.getCmp('move-next').setDisabled(!layout.getNext());
};

Ext.define('App.view.RequestPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.requestpanel',

    title: 'Request Panel',
    items: [{
        html: 'Sample Result'
    }],
    bbar: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Search'
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Reset'
    }]
});

Ext.define('App.view.ResultPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.resultpanel',

    title: 'Result Panel',
    layout: 'card',

    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel', // Standard panel, but this could be another super complex panel
        html: 'Sample Result 1'
    }, {
        // Defaults to xtype: 'panel', if no xtype is specified
        html: 'Sample Result 2'
    }, {
        // Defaults to xtype: 'panel', if no xtype is specified
        html: 'Sample Result 3'
    }, {
        // Defaults to xtype: 'panel', if no xtype is specified
        html: 'Sample Result 4'
    }],
    bbar: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Previous',
        handler: function (btn) {
            navigate(btn.up('panel'), 'prev');
        }

    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Next',
        handler: function (btn) {
            navigate(btn.up('panel'), 'next');
        }
    }]
});

Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    layout: 'border',
    items: [{
        region: 'north',
        html: '<h1 class="x-panel-header">Sencha</h1>',
        border: false
    }, {
        xtype: 'requestpanel', // Your super complex panel
        region: 'center', // Context specific properties for the panel
        layout: 'fit', // Context specific properties for the panel
        flex: 1 // Context specific properties for the panel
    }, {
        region: 'south', // Your super complex panel
        xtype: 'resultpanel', // Context specific properties for the panel
        flex: 1, // Context specific properties for the panel
        collapsible: true, // Context specific properties for the panel
        split: true
    }]
});
```

**Edit:** Updated Fiddle and code example to use `Ext.define`

Comment: You have a property `hidden: true` on the panel with the buttons. Second, the center region of a border layout cannot be collapsible. Third, you are creating a panel inside a panel. That's unnecessary overnesting, follow my example or look at Ext.define.

Comment: ​Thanks for the​ ​​​quick ​response.​​ ​​We can not put the request Panel and reesponse Panel inside the viewport. The panels are very complex.

Comment: So, use `Ext.define`. I've updated the Fiddle and code example. You should also read the comments I've included in the example. If your app is complex, also look at MVC as I suggested.